# How to prioritize a file over a directory in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

For example, there is example.com/graphics (as a directory), and there is example.com/graphics.html (as a file). You need to make sure that from example.com/graphics (directory) there is a redirect to example.com/graphics.html. But at the same time, .html should be removed from the link.

A lot of things, but nothing helped. There is only code that removes .html

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Problem solved.
Previously, I used GitHub pages, where in order to access the file, you had to create it in the root of the site. To do the same on Apache, we had to create an index.html file in the graphics directory.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `/graphics` directory? Are you serving files from this directory?

Comment: @MrWhite there are other html files

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Previously, I used GitHub pages, where in order to access the file, you had to create it in the root of the site. To do the same on Apache, we had to create an index.html file in the graphics directory.

Comment: You can do the same on Apache, as you were doing on GitHub pages if you want. Is the trailing slash desirable or not?

Comment: @MrWhite Slash on the end is not needed.